# asp.net Chart unknown error

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, plesk

I have been some time using asp.net charts, even it was hard to config for asp 3.5 and to make it work, I have been able to move along with all my project but I'm facing something that I have no idea how to solve.

This project works perfectly on my develop enviroment, but when i deployed it on the server, the only page with charts on it appeared like this:

[image]

I assume its cause of the charts because its the only thing that really have given me problems and its the only thing that its exclusively on this page but i have no idea how this happens, it only happens on the server with Plesk.

Tried to upload on debug instead of release but the result is the same. Searched overall but never found anything like this.

Comment: As far as I expericed, this shows up instread of the error page due a bad config of the error handling on the web config or global.asax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer may not give you the exact solution. But it may give you an idea's.

Below are my Ideas:

1. Make Sure you have included all the files into your solution when you do the Build.
2. Make Sure you have all dependency of `Asp.Net Charts` in Server.
3. Check you browser `Console` and `Browser Network`. Press **F12** in your and check. You can get to know the Exact problem if any issue in loading prob / dependency files.
4. Double check your server configurations for the charts. And compare your local and server configs.
5. Do the Deployment in your machine itself and check one round.

Comment: Im not sure if any of this did the trick, one of the tries i did on the normal IIS (localhost) instread of the Plesk httpdocs path worked, once that, all worked on plesk.